# Return most common, 2nd most common, 3rd most common, etc. text string in an excel array

Tags: arrays, excel

I need to find the most common words from multiple columns. Below is an example where I was able to find when searching from only column A. How can I edit the current formula to get the result for multiple columns?

```
    A   B   C
2   Harmon  _   Williams
3   Smith   _   Smith
4   Smith   _   Harmon
5   Harmon  _   _
6   Williams    _   _
7   Williams    _   _
8   Smith   _   _
9   Williams    _   _
10  Williams    _
```

Enter this array formula** in C2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A2:A10,MODE(MATCH(A2:A10,A2:A10,0)+{0,0})),"")
```

Enter this array formula** in C3 and copy down until you get blanks:

=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$10,MODE(IF(COUNTIF(C$2:C2,A$2:A$10)=0,MATCH(A$2:A$10,A$2:A$10,0)+{0,0}))),"")

Comment: Just concatenate A and B into a third column and apply your array formula to that third column (i.e. `=A&B` or `=A&" "&B` if readability matters)

Comment: Thanks but If I concatenate, it will not give me the most common text in the data which would not allow for the result i am looking for

Comment: In that case please add input and desired output for the case when you have words in columns B as well